# What is the correct syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a sql query to update data of 'tbl_products'.
Here is the query

```sql
update tbl_products 
set product_count = (product_count - tbl_order_details.product_sales_quantity) 
from tbl_products 
join tbl_order_details on tbl_order_details.product_id = tbl_products.product_id 
join tbl_order on tbl_order.order_id = tbl_order_details.order_id 
where tbl_order.order_id = 54;
```

But it gives me the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from tbl_products join tbl_order_details on tbl_order_details.product_id = tbl_p' at line 1

What's wrong here?

Comment: See: [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). Note that `FROM ...` and `JOIN ...` belong to ***table_references***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, the correct syntax is:

```
update tbl_products p join
       tbl_order_details od
       on od.product_id = p.product_id join
       tbl_order o
       on o.order_id = od.order_id 
    set p.product_count = (p.product_count - od.product_sales_quantity) 
    where o.order_id = 54;
```